# Exporting from DB with another encoding

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a exporting code:

```
$prihlaseni = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Nelze se připojit k databázi!");
$db = mysql_select_db("f60342");
$najit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_modified DESC LIMIT 1");

while($v = mysql_fetch_object($najit)){
    $obsah = $v->post_content;
    echo "
        <p style='margin-bottom: 20px;'>$obsah</p>
    ";
}
```

Data is stored in DB with **uf8_general_ci** encoding and changing the coding in PhpMyAdmin does not work (I don't want to solve this).

It exports letters as "ř,š,ž..." (czech letters) as question mark. Is there any way to export that from DB in a utf-8 coding, which would export those letters normally?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: `WHERE IN()`? In what? In nothing? That seems extraneous or perhaps missing something important.

Comment: Sorry, that was a remain from my trying to solve this :D

Comment: If you're writing this within WordPress, use [the WPDB database layer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks). Don't make your own connections to the database, especially via things like `mysql_query`.

Comment: I'm rebuilding a webstie which was a WordPress site and was hacked and the only thing I have is the DB (because the website files were deleted by hosting owner).

Comment: If you've already been hacked the last thing you want to do is expose yourself to more risks. Don't use `mysql_query`, it's the source of a lot of these problems because it's very hard to use perfectly. A single mistake is all an attacker needs to get into your database and inject whatever they want.

Comment: I'm using this on my local hosting a I use it just for getting the data from the DB. So this is no a problem. A solution for this problem would be helpful...

Comment: This is a UTF-8 all-the-way problem. Make sure everything in your chain, from file, to source code, to connection is UTF-8.